# mysql_query() error "You have an error in your SQL syntax" in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I tried find solution but didn't find it.

## Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

## Query:

```
$uQuery = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = '.$_SESSION['user']) or die(mysql_error());
$userRow = mysql_fetch_array($uQuery);
```

Can anyone please tell what's wrong with my code?

Comment: What is the value of `$_SESSION['user']`? You should be sanitizing it: `mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user'])`

Comment: The problem is that you are lacking the ticks `'` around `$_SESSION['user']`. Your query would give `...where \`user_id\`=John` but it should be `...where \`user_id\`='John'`.

Comment: And please consider using prepared statements (those with `?`) because your statement will [dramatically fail](https://xkcd.com/327/) if the given user_id is `John'); drop table users;--`.

Comment: Stop using `MySQL_` it is deprecated. Use `MySQLi_` or `PDO` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the value of $_SESSION['user']?

Also, have you written session_start() on top of the page?

You may wanna debug it. Try this:

```
var_dump($_SESSION['user']);

$uQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = '".$_SESSION['user']."' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're welcome. Please vote the answer up and accept it if you're satisfied with it. Peace! :)

Answer (score -3):

`$_SESSION['user']` should be `$_SESSION[user]`